# Optimize query with a subquery With Group BY MAX and JOINED with another TABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

[image]I need help to optimize this SQL query, so that it would run much faster.

What I am trying to do is, get the latest values of DATA out of these tables:

TABLE: Quotes
ID    QuoteNumber     LastUpdated(inticks) PolicyId
1        C1000         1000000000000         100
1        D2000         1001111111110         200
2        A1000         1000000000000         300
2        B2000         1002222222222         400

TABLE: Policies
ID    CustomerName  Blah1(dummy column)
100        Mark     someData
200        Lisa     someData2
300        Brett    someData3
400        Goku     someData4

DESIRED RESULT:
LastUpdated     Id(quoteId)  QuoteNumber   CustomerName
1001111111110-      -1-          -D2000-         -Lisa
1002222222222-      -2-          -B2000-         -Goku

```
Select DISTINCT subquery1.LastUpdated,
                q2.Id, 
                q2.QuoteNumber,
                p.CustomerName 
                FROM
                (Select q.id, 
                            Max(q.LastUpdated) from Quotes q
                            where q.LastUpdated > @someDateTimeParameter
                            and q.QuoteNumber is not null
                            and q.IsDiscarded = 0
                            GROUP BY q.id) as subquery1
LEFT JOIN Quotes q2
on q2.id = subquery1.id
and q2.LastUpdated = subquery1.LastUpdated
INNER JOIN Policies p
on p.id = q2.PolicyId
where p.blah1 = @someBlahParameter
ORDER BY subquery1.LastUpdated
```

Here is the actual execution plan:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkD3fPdwD

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the queries does would help.  Similarly, table size and layout information is helpful as well an information about current run times.

Comment: Images of the plan don't fully help us, use paste the plan (linked above). Though that image implies there is very little data involved, so if this is running slow I suspect it is not the query itself and something else; such as a bandwidth issue or a server with very low specs.

Comment: Now we see your code is paging the resultset, which makes your original post very deceiving. And without DDL for the tables it is just a game of guessing. I can tell you that your left join in absolutely pointless. Did you throw DISTINCT in your query for a reason?

Comment: @SMor   yeah because of duplicates I did distinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this

```
with q_cte as (
    select q.Id, q.QuoteNumber, q.LastUpdated, 
           row_number() over (partition by q.id order by q.LastUpdated desc) rn
    from Quotes q
    where q.LastUpdated>@someDateTimeParameter
          and q.QuoteNumber is not null
          and q.IsDiscarded=0)
select q.*, p.CustomerName 
from q_cte q
     join Policies p on q.PolicyId=p.id
where q.rn=1 /* Only the lastest date */
      and p.blah1=someBlahParameter
order by q.LastUpdated;
```